# IIS6 app pool credential causes site to say "Access is denied"

Tags: iis, iis-6

Ok I'm stumped. I've configured an IIS 6 website with its own App Pool, which has its own AD domain credential. When I attempt to browse the site, I see a page that simply says "Access is denied.". There is no error code or information in Event Logs.

I am able to open Notepad with the app pool account credentials (and open the html file I'm trying to browse).

If I add the app pool's domain account to the local administrators group, the site loads. However, this is not acceptable for our environment.

I have successfully configured this site on two servers (that are supposed to be identical in a load-balanced pair). However, try as I might, I can't find any difference between these two servers' configurations.

Comment: Its look like a Server Fault (http://serverfault.com/) question, Stackoverflow is about code ;)

Comment: I thought about that, but it looked like there were a lot more IIS related questions on here. Is there some way to move the question?

Comment: It'll be moved by 3000+ users if needed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled IIS 6 and the error has gone away. After reinstalling IIS, I had to reinstall .NET 4 as well.

Thank you very much for your suggestions and advice though!

Comment: No problem, if you consider your answer is resolved your problem, don't hesitate to accept it. It is ok on stackexchange network and will help the community.

Answer (score 0):

Is your pool identity present in the local group `IIS_WPG` ?

This group ensure the Worker Process will have the required privileges to run correctly.

Also, your WebSite root folder must have Read permissions for `IIS_WPG`, which is the case if your root is in `Inetpub\wwwroot`.

Same for `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.x.x.x\Temporary ASP.NET Files` **+ Write**, if you run ASP.NET WebSites.

FYI, in IIS 7, the group is now known as IIS_IUSRS.

[Default permissions and user rights for IIS 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812614/en-us)

[Configuring Application Pool Identity in IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/12a3d96c-65ea-4210-96ad-86a801f6a88c.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. The app pool identity is in the IIS_WPG group, and I verified the permissions you listed. When I replace the app pool identity with the identity from another app pool that works fine on this same server, this new site works fine as well. However, when I compare the accounts in AD, they are members of the same groups. I checked the local groups and neither are members of any except IIS_WPG (as you mentioned).